# How can I convert a timestamp to seconds in java script

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this:

```
00:07:57,685
```

to seconds.
It should return `00*60 + 07*60 + 57,685`
The problem is its format I did not manage to write an optimized function.

Comment: Can you clarify the input format? Is this `HH:MM:SS,sss`?

Comment: Yes exactly it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const input = "00:07:57,685";
const [hours, minutes, secondsRaw] = input.split(/:/g);
const seconds = secondsRaw.replace(",", ".");

let output = 0;
output += parseInt(hours) * 3600;
output += parseInt(minutes) * 60;
output += parseFloat(seconds);

console.log(`${output} seconds`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample :

```
function stringTimeToSecond (stringTime) {
    // convert from "," float notation to "." float notation
    // split your string to [h, m, s]
    // reverse to get [s, m, h] to be able to use indice on the reduce method
    const stringTimeArray = stringTime.replace(',','.').split(":").reverse();
    // 60^0 = 1 for seconds
    // 60^1 = 60 for minutes
    // 60^2 = 3600 for hours
    return stringTimeArray.reduce((timeInSecond, time, i) => {
         timeInSecond += time * Math.pow(60, i);
         return timeInSecond;
    }, 0);
}
```

Reduce method will iterate through your array and then return your accumulator "timeInSecond". The accumulator is initialized to 0 as the second argument of the reduce function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work if i understood your question right:

```js
let timestamp = "00:07:57,685"
let seconds = timestamp.split(":")[2].split(",")[0]
```